# how to get information during mouseover in d3

Tags: d3.js, charts, chart.js

I am using and working on d3 chart. Now my functionality is I create a div dynamically and put the color in div using scale.
Linear it's working fine now my need is i need like google pinrest like location notify i put it in all div when i mouseover it i need to show what color name code is there in particular div help how to do this.

Here attached my code and what image should be placed inside the div just for refrence any image can placed inside the div

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TMCby/12/

***Snippet:***

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title></title>
  <style type="text/css" media="screen">
    div {
      width: 60px;
      height: 60px;
      float: left;
      margin: 1px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    debugger;
    var body = d3.select("body"),
      length = 10,
      color = d3.scale.linear().domain([1, length])

      .range(["blue", "red"]);


    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
      body.append('div').attr('style', function(d) {
        return 'background-color: ' + color(i);
      });
    }
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Append img tag to each div and set the title attribute of the image as its container div color.

```js
var body = d3.select("body"),
  length = 10,
  color = d3.scale.linear().domain([1, length]).range(["blue", "red"]);

for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
  body.append('div')
    .attr('style', function(d) {
      return 'background-color: ' + color(i);
    })
    .append("img")
    .attr("height", "15px")
    .attr("width", "15px")
    .attr("src", "https://i.stack.imgur.com/O9xB5.png")
    .attr("title", color(i));
}
```

```css
div {
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  float: left;
  margin: 1px;
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44039946/how-to-plot-the-image-inside-the-polygon-in-d3  help@@Gilsha

Comment: hi @Gilsha any suggestion

Comment: Looking at your code. Created a fiddle now. Wait for a few minutes.