# how to plot the image inside the polygon in d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts

hi all i am using d3 chart with polygon i have one map structure d3 chart and plot one circle for the purpose of show tooltip now my need is i need to show one image 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/O9xB5.png' to replace the circle so when mouse over the image i shown tooltip and another need show 'State Abbr' inside polygon like Ak,TD,PD...
 .help ow to do this here i attached my code files

## code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">

/* On mouse hover, lighten state color */
path:hover {
    fill-opacity: .7;
}

/* Style for Custom Tooltip */
div.tooltip {   
    position: absolute;           
    text-align: center;           
    width: 60px;                  
    height: 28px;                 
    padding: 2px;             
    font: 12px sans-serif;        
    background: white;   
    border: 0px;      
    border-radius: 8px;           
    pointer-events: none;         
}

/* Legend Font Style */
body {
    font: 11px sans-serif;
}

/* Legend Position Style */
.legend {
    position:absolute;
    left:800px;
    top:350px;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">         
//Width and height of map
var width = 960;
var height = 500;   
// D3 Projection
var projection = d3.geo.albersUsa()
                   .translate([width/2, height/2])    
                   .scale([1000]);         

// Define path generator
var path = d3.geo.path()               
             .projection(projection);      

// Define linear scale for output
var color = d3.scale.linear()
              .range(["green","red"]);

var legendText = ["Population Present", "Population Absent"]; 
var svg = d3.select("body")
            .append("svg")

            .attr("width", width)
            .attr("height", height);
var div = d3.select("body")
            .append("div")   

            .attr("class", "tooltip")  

             .style("opacity", 0);

// Load in my states data!
d3.csv("Population_education.csv", function(data) {

// Load GeoJSON data and merge with states data
d3.json("us-states.json", function(json) {

// Loop through each state data value in the .csv file
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    // Grab State Name
    var dataState = data[i].SiteState;

    // Get Population
    var dataPop = data[i].Population;

    // Grab data value 
    if(data[i].Members > 0) {
    var dataValue = 1;
    } 
    else { var dataValue = 0;}
    // Find the corresponding state inside the GeoJSON
    for (var j = 0; j < json.features.length; j++)  {
        var jsonState = json.features[j].properties.name;
        if (dataState == jsonState) {
        // Copy the data value into the JSON
        json.features[j].properties.MembersPresent = dataValue;
        json.features[j].properties.pop = +dataPop;
        // Stop looking through the JSON
        break;
        }

    }
}

// Get Max and Min Population and update colorscale
var max = d3.max(json.features, function(d) { return d.properties.pop });
var min = d3.min(json.features, function(d) { return d.properties.pop })

color.domain([min, max]); // setting the range of the input data

// Bind the data to the SVG and create one path per GeoJSON feature
svg.selectAll("path")
    .data(json.features)
    .enter().append("path")
        .attr("d", path)
        .style("stroke", "#fff")
        .style("stroke-width", "1")       
        .style("fill", function(d) {
            return color(d.properties.pop)
        });



// Map the cities I have lived in!
d3.csv("Population_education.csv", function(data) {

svg.selectAll("circle")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("circle")
    .attr("cx", function(d) {
        if (d.AvgLng != 0 && d.AvgLat != 0)
        return projection([d.AvgLng, d.AvgLat])[0];
    })
    .attr("cy", function(d) {
    if (d.AvgLng != 0 && d.AvgLat != 0)
        return projection([d.AvgLng, d.AvgLat])[1];
    })
    .attr("r", function(d) {
        return 3;
    })
        .style("fill", "rgb(217,91,67)")    
        .style("opacity", 0.45) 
    .on("mouseover", function(d) {      
        div.transition()        
           .duration(200)      
           .style("opacity", .9);
           div.html("State:" + d['State Abbr'] + "<br/>"  + "Pop:" + d.Population)
           .style("left", (d3.event.pageX) + "px")     
           .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 28) + "px");    
    })   
    .on("mouseout", function(d) {       
        div.transition()        
           .duration(500)      
           .style("opacity", 0);   
    });
}); 

var legend = d3.select("body").append("svg")
                .attr("class", "legend")
                .attr("width", 140)
                .attr("height", 200)
                .selectAll("g")
                .data(color.domain().slice().reverse())
                .enter()
                .append("g")
                .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(0," + i * 20 + ")"; });

    legend.append("rect")
          .attr("width", 18)
          .attr("height", 18)
          .style("fill", color);

    legend.append("text")
          .data(legendText)
          .attr("x", 24)
          .attr("y", 9)
          .attr("dy", ".35em")
          .text(function(d) { return d; });
    });

});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

## Data

Population_education.csv

```
RowID,SiteState,State Abbr,AvgLat,AvgLng,Population
1,Alabama,AL,32.806671,-86.79113,28
2,Arizona,AZ,33.729759,-111.431221,11704
3,California,CA,36.116203,-119.681564,4356448
4,Colorado,CO,39.059811,-105.311104,374435
5,Connecticut,CT,41.597782,-72.755371,455966
6,Florida,FL,27.766279,-81.68678300000001,442537
7,Georgia,GA,33.040619,-83.643074,1339081
8,Illinois,IL,40.349457,-88.986137,29
9,Indiana,IN,39.849426,-86.258278,1525124
10,Iowa,IA,42.011539,-93.210526,185146
11,Kansas,KS,38.5266,-96.72648599999999,129301
12,Kentucky,KY,37.66814,-84.670067,621047
13,Louisiana,LA,31.169546,-91.867805,170568
14,Maine,ME,44.693947,-69.381927,222966
15,Maryland,MD,39.063946,-76.80210099999999,256966
16,Massachusetts,MA,42.230171,-71.530106,27
17,Michigan,MI,43.326618,-84.536095,27
18,Minnesota,MN,45.694454,-93.900192,11
19,Missouri,MO,38.456085,-92.28836800000001,420415
20,Nevada,NV,38.313515,-117.055374,309799
21,New Hampshire,NH,43.452492,-71.563896,195948
22,New Jersey,NJ,40.298904,-74.521011,241039
23,New Mexico,NM,34.840515,-106.248482,1945
24,New York,NY,42.165726,-74.94805100000001,1075153
25,North Carolina,NC,35.630066,-79.80641900000001,14
26,Ohio,OH,40.388783,-82.764915,1526404
27,Oregon,OR,44.572021,-122.070938,11
28,Pennsylvania,PA,40.590752,-77.209755,197
29,South Carolina,SC,33.856892,-80.945007,45
30,Tennessee,TN,35.747845,-86.692345,446667
31,Texas,TX,31.054487,-97.563461,736672
32,Vermont,VA,37.769337,-78.169968,2324640
33,Washington,WA,47.400902,-121.490494,141319
34,West Virginia,WV,38.491226,-80.954453,128275
35,Wisconsin,WI,44.268543,-89.616508,405942
36,Alaska,AK,0,0,0
37,Arkansas,AR,0,0,0
38,Delaware,DE,0,0,0
39,District of Columbia,DC,0,0,0
40,Hawaii,HI,0,0,0
41,Idaho,ID,0,0,0
42,Mississippi,MS,0,0,0
43,Montana,MT,0,0,0
44,Nebraska,NE,0,0,0
45,North Dakota,ND,0,0,0
46,South Dakota,SD,0,0,0
47,Utah,UT,0,0,0
48,Virginia,VT,0,0,0
49,Wyoming,WY,0,0,0
50,Oklahoma,OK,0,0,0
51,Rhode Island,RI,0,0,0
```

My us-states.json is as in the following link https://raw.githubusercontent.com/alignedleft/d3-book/master/chapter_12/us-states.json

Comment: Hi Jose, Just to confirm, Is my answer useful, are u still facing issues?

Comment: working fine thanks..@Glisha

Answer (score 3):

Code to add image and tooltip to each polygon.

```
paths.each(function(d) {
    if (this.getTotalLength() > 0) {
      var midPoint = path.centroid(d);          
      svg.append("svg:image")
        .attr("height", "15px")
        .attr("width", "15px")
        .attr("xlink:href", "https://i.stack.imgur.com/O9xB5.png")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + midPoint[0] + ",  " + midPoint[1] + ")")
        .append("title")
        .text(d.properties.abbr);
      svg.append("svg:text")
        .attr("x", midPoint[0])
        .attr("y", midPoint[1])
        .text(d.properties.abbr);
    }
});
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gilsha/w4urapds/)

To include abbr details to the data, code as shown below.

```
// Find the corresponding state inside the GeoJSON
for (var j = 0; j < json.features.length; j++) {
    var jsonState = json.features[j].properties.name;
    if (dataState == jsonState) {
       // Copy the data value into the JSON
       json.features[j].properties.MembersPresent = dataValue;
       json.features[j].properties.pop = +dataPop;
       json.features[j].properties.abbr = data[i]["State Abbr"];
       // Stop looking through the JSON
       break;
    }
}
```

Comment: i need to show Sate Abr inside the polygon @Gilsha not in tool tip – and one plotting is out of graph kindly  once check

Comment: Updated in answer

Comment: one plotting is out of graph kindly once check @Gilsha

Comment: i have another issue help @Gilsha

Comment: Is this regarding the same question?

Comment: yes.i need to show color legend based on map color when i click the legend color that color only should show other polygon are going to fade @Gilsha

Comment: Okay. Let me check. Actually, you should be asking this as a new question.

Comment: Jose, Currently, you have two legends only. But the map has paths with many colors. Why is this so?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44126836/how-to-make-clcikable-legend-visible-in-d3-polygon-chart

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144897/discussion-between-gilsha-and-jose).